# how to define an arrayList with two columns in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a hashMap. Each "Value"is going to be a a list which will be mapped later on with my "Key"s. List is desired to look like this:

[length,time][length,time][length,time]

For example:
Key{srcAddr=x, dstAddr=y, srcPort=12345, dstPort=80}
value{(6523,0.001),(124,0.05), () , (), ...}

I just wonder how can I have a two-col arrayList.

```
package myclassifier;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FlowStatics {
int packetLength;
double timeArrival;
public FlowStatics(int pLength, double tArrival)
{
    this.packetLength = pLength;
    this.timeArrival = tArrival;


}
```

}
and here is how I used it:

```
final ArrayList<FlowStatics> staticsArray = new ArrayList<FlowStatics>();
final HashMap<Flows, ArrayList> myHashMap = new HashMap<Flows, ArrayList>();

FlowStatics flowStatics = new FlowStatics(packetLength,timeArrival);
staticsArray.add(flowStatics);
myHashMap.put(flows, staticsArray);
```

and here is the part that I am reading it:

```
Iterator<Flows> iterator =  myHashMap.keySet().iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    Flows key = iterator.next();
    ArrayList value = myHashMap.get(key);
    System.out.println("Fows"+key+"----------"+"Statics"+ value);
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, your `FlowStatics` is the correct solution

`List<FlowStatics>` will give you the "two-column array list".

Update: as of your update, `myHashMap.put(flows, flowStatics);` is wrong. You are this putting an individual pair, rather than a list in the map. You should use:

```
staticsArray.add(flowStatics);
myHashMap.put(flows, staticsArray);
```

Comment: as I changed my hashMap, it doesnt work anymore at all. im not getting any error, but iterating over my hashMap takes too long and the output is the same as before.

Comment: i also did override toString method.

Answer (score 3):

A [`List<E>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is an abstraction for a homogeneous list of elements whose type is `E`. There are some restrictions (e.g. no primitives), but conceptually the type `E` can be defined to be whatever you want.

Suppose there's an abstraction of `Pair<L,R>`. Then a `List<Pair<L,R>>` is still a list of some `E`, but now that `E` is a `Pair<L,R>`. So it's still a "one-column" list, but each element in the list is a "pair", so it's sort of a "two-column" list.

Note that you don't always need a generic `Pair<L,R>`. Any type `E` that properly encapsulates all the information can be used in a `List<E>`.

And by the way, you can have a `List<List<E>>` too.

#### See also

- [Wikipedia/Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28computer_science%29)

#### Related questions

- [What is the equivalent of the C++ `Pair<L,R>` in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java)
- [List of Lists of Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102761/list-of-lists-of-lists)

---

#### Returning values analogy

Often people ask "How can I return two values in Java?". The answer is analogous. You return one value, a new type which encapsulates both information.

So instead of:

```
// attempt to return two values
// DOES NOT COMPILE

return "James Bond";
return "007";
```

You do:

```
return new SecretAgent("James Bond", "007");
```

#### Related questions

- [Using a java method to return multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736061/using-a-java-method-to-return-multiple-values)

Comment: thanks for your comprehensive answer. I'd thought about pair too but as the number of statistical factors which I am considering may grow, that why i didnt use it.
I am still wondering what is my problem, as I am adding object to an arraylist.