# Return more than one value from a function in Java

Tags: java, tuples, return-type

How to return more than one value from a function in Java?
Can anyone give sample code for doing this using tuples?
I am not able to understand the concept of tuples.

---

```
public class Tuple{
    public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println(f());
    }
    static Pair<String,Integer> f(){
        return new Pair<String,Integer>("hi",3);
    }
    public class Pair<String,Integer> {
        public final String a;
        public final Integer b;

        public Pair(String a, Integer b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
    }
}
```

What is the mistake in the above code?

Comment: Java doesn't have tuples. If you like them, switch to Scala.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return multiple objects from a Java method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457629/how-to-return-multiple-objects-from-a-java-method)

Comment: i always use HashMap for it. You can put whatever you want , keyed by your choice of names. its like a batch

Answer (score 4):

Create a class that holds multiple values you need. In your method, return an object that's an instance of that class. Voila!

This way, you still return **one** object. In Java, you cannot return more than *one* object, whatever that may be.

Comment: To be precise you return a _reference_ to an object.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
public class Tuple {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(f().a);
        System.out.println(f().b);
    }

    static Pair<String, Integer> f() {
        Tuple t = new Tuple();
        return t.new Pair<String, Integer>("hi", 3);

    }

    public class Pair<String, Integer> {
        public final String a;
        public final Integer b;

        public Pair(String a, Integer b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't return more than one value.

You can return  Array,Collection if it satisfies your purpose.

**Note:** It would be one value, reference to your Object[of array,collection] would be return.

Answer (score 1):

You can return an array from a java function:

```
   public static int[] ret() {
      int[] foo = {1,2,3,4};
      return  foo;
   }
```

Comment: Still just one object (or reference to it...). The answer is 'no', but you can return an array, a collection, or a custom object encapsulating multiple objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return more than one value in java ( which is not python ). Write a method that just returns array or list or any other object like this

Answer (score 0):

What if what you are returning are of different data types just like your situation. Or for example, Lets say you are returning a String name and an integer age. You can you JSON from the org.json library. You can get the jar at 
    http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm

```
public JSONObject info(){
     String name = "Emil";
     int age = 25;
     String jsonString  ="{\"name\":\""+ name+"\",\"age\":"+ age +"}";
     JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
     return json ;
}
```

Afterwards, if you want to get the data somewhere in your program, this is what you do:

```
//objectInstanceName is the name of the instantiated class
JSONObject jso = objectInstanceName.info();
String name = jso.getString("name");
int age = jso.getInt("age");
System.out.println(name + " is "+ age + " years old");

//Output will be like
Emil is 25 years old
```

Hope you try it. Or you can read more on JSON in java if you  HAVEN'T.