# How to return all value from a function

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to return all values of dbManagement.ORIGINATING_ADDRESS from this function but it just gives me last one value to blockedNumber. I know it'll give last one value but how can i get all value. kindly help

```
public String selectBlockedNumbers() {
        Cursor cursor = dbManagement.selectBlockedNumbers();
        String blockedNumber = null;
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        for(int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
            blockedNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbManagement.ORIGINATING_ADDRESS));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, blockedNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return blockedNumber;

    }
```

In

```
Cursor cursor = dbManagement.selectBlockedNumbers();
```

the function selectBlockedNumbers() consist of following query:

`cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + ORIGINATING_ADDRESS + " FROM " + TABLE_BLOCK_LIST, null);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the for-loop runs for the last time, blockedNumbers  will contain the last number retrieved. So, instead of returning a `String`, rather returns a `List<String>`. In that case your code should change into

```
public List<String> selectBlockedNumbers() {
        Cursor cursor = dbManagement.selectBlockedNumbers();
        List<String> blockedNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        for(int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
            String blockedNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbManagement.ORIGINATING_ADDRESS));
            blockedNumbers.add(blockedNumber);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, blockedNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return blockedNumbers;    
    }
```

Comment: thanks for help. it return List<String> but i required only String type.

Comment: basically i want to retreive these blockedNumbers and need to compare with a String

Comment: Can you please share the code where you do the comparison? I can then suggest how you can modify it to work with the returned `List<String>`

Comment: I want to compare with  String s = "123";

Comment: In that case you want to check if any of the blocked numbers is "123" - you do this:                                                                                `List<String> blockedNumbers = selectBlockedNumbers();            
   for(String blockedNumber : blockedNumbers){
    if("123".equals(blockedNumber)){
     //do something here?
    }
   }`

Comment: Sorry, the code formatting got out of hand - please see my comment above yours. I show how you can then compare the returned numbers against "123" - please check if this solves your problem.

Comment: your effort highly appreciated. but i want a function which return only String so after it i just put this function to another file to compare values.

Comment: In that case, please understand that it is not possible to return more than one String value as you desire (unless you'd rather return comma-separated string - containing blocked numbers separated by comma like "123,456") - please see related questions and consider their suggestions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285270/is-it-possible-to-return-more-than-one-value-from-a-method-in-java, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457629/how-to-return-multiple-objects-from-a-java-method as well as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756558/return-more-than-one-value-from-a-function-in-java.