# Return Tuple from Java Method

Tags: java, tuples

I wrote a java class:

```
public class Tuple<X, Y> { 
  public final X x; 
  public final Y y; 
  public Tuple(X x, Y y) { 
    this.x = x; 
    this.y = y; 
  } 
}
```

but when I create a function like this:

```
public Tuple<boolean, String> getResult()
{
    try {
        if(something.equals(something2))
             return new Tuple(true, null);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        return new Tuple(false, e.getMessage());
}
```

However, I get the following compilation error:

```
unexpected type
  required: reference
  found:    boolean
```

What I can do?

Comment: _"required: reference; found: boolean"_  This is telling you it found the type `boolean` where it was expecting a "reference" type, i.e. some sort of Object.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Generics aren't for primitive types. Use [`Boolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) instead of `boolean`.

```
public Tuple<Boolean, String> getResult() {
    //your code goes here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is why classes like Boolen, Integer,Long etc got introduced. There are several apis in java where an object is expected and not a primitive.