# java singleton boolean expression to return message instead of true or false

Tags: java, boolean, singleton, message

How can we get the boolean expression of a basic singleton with hashsets to return a message in lieu of the original 'true' or 'false'?

```
public boolean bookLane(String lane) {
    return runLane.remove(lane);
}
```

I want to only replace the true or false return statements with a message.

To help clarify this question, something like below (i know it doesn't work) is the direction I am wanting to go...

```
public boolean bookLane(String lane) {
    if (true)
    {
        message = "Lane is available. Adding runner...";
        //instead of true
    }
    else
    {
        message = "Lane unavailable. Please choose another";
        //instead of false
    }
    return runLane.remove(lane);
}
```

I just tried messing with the code and found that it only returns false now.

```
public boolean bookLane(String lane) {
    String message1 = "Lane Available. Adding runner...";
    String message2 = "Lane is Unavailable.";
    if (runLane.remove(lane))
    {
        System.out.println(message1);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(message2);
    }
    return runLane.remove(lane);//
}
```

Any ideas on fixing it? Not gonna lie, my experience with Java is mainly trial and error with a little help from more experienced programmers. I think this method could work if someone could let me know what I am missing as far as how boolean methods work with more than just the one return type. I am trying to target the return value for displaying the appropriate message with the returned boolean. Is this route even possible? Am I missing some logic in how boolean methods work or something? Please understand my frustration and my need for yalls help. thanks for the guidance given...

Comment: A method returning a boolean can only return a boolean. Not a String. If you want to return a message, then change the return type to String. But really, the caller of the method should use the boolean returned value to choose a message and, I guess, display it.

Comment: As @JBNizet wrote: change return type from `boolean` to `String`. Then assign `runLane.remove(lane)` to a local variable at first and use it for your logic to pick the message to return.

Comment: Could this be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470861/return-multiple-values-from-a-java-method-why-no-n-tuple-objects ?

Comment: @AlexErohin that seems more like a debate than anything else. I like cutting straight to the chase. there are no other posts like this.

Comment: Are you saying that in your updated code you can't get the `true` case even if you remove the lane which is in `runLane`? To check it do `System.out.println("contains? " + runLane.contains(lane);` . If it prints `contains? true` and still `message1` isn't printed, that would be strange at least.

Answer (score 0):

In these cases it might be useful to define a new data structure, since you want to retrieve two pieces of information from the same method. Consider the following:

```
class BookLaneResult {
    boolean success;
    String message;
    // add constructors / getters / other stuff you need
}
```

Then your code becomes this:

```
public BookLaneResult bookLane(String lane) {
    // some logic to determine if lane is available or not
    boolean laneAvaiable = ...;

    return new BookLaneResult(laneAvailable, laneAvailable ? "Lane available" : "Lane unavailable");
}
```

If the `BookLaneResult` is to be used only in that case with only those messages, then you can just use a `boolean` parameter constructor and set the message based on the argument internally. However, to make the new data structure more flexible you can name it `OperationResult` and use it whenever you perform some kind of operation and expect to retrieve a boolean flag representing the operation success or failure and the message stating what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I used for a boolean operation trying to figure out if a character is a letter - if it is a letter, true, false if no.

**Code**

```
boolean isLetter = Character.isLetter(ch); 
    if (isLetter == true) {
        Boolean.toString(isLetter); 
        System.out.println(" This is a letter."); }
    else  {
        Boolean.toString(isLetter);
        System.out.println(" This is not a letter."); }
```

Worked for me - might be able to apply to other boolean operations.

**Output**

```
Input data: 123456abcdef
1  2 This is not a letter
2  3 This is not a letter
3  4 This is not a letter
4  5 This is not a letter
5  6 This is not a letter
6  7 This is not a letter
a  b This is a letter
b  c This is a letter
c  d This is a letter
d  e This is a letter
e  f This is a letter
f  g This is a letter
```

I realize this is years late, but including this for those who pop up on this thread from a Google search.