# Function with multiple outputs in Java

Tags: java

How to create a JAVA function with multiple outputs?
Something like:

```
private (ArrayList<Integer[]>, int indexes) sortObjects(ArrayList<Integer[]> arr) {
//...
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by multiple outputs? Are you referring to the return values? If this is the case, you should create a new class instead, and put your arraylist, int indexes and whatever else you want in there. Then modify the function to return your newly created class.

Comment: How about using a HashMap ?

Answer (score 5):

Java's not like Python - no tuples.  You have to create an Object and wrap all your outputs into it.  Another solution might be a Collection of some sort, but I think the former means better encapsulation.

Comment: Ouh, examples are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457629/how-to-return-multiple-objects-from-a-java-method

Answer (score 2):

In some cases it is possible to use method arguments to handle result values. In your case, part of the result is a list (which may be updated destructively). So you could change your method-signature to the following form:

```
private int sortObjects(ArrayList<Integer[]> input, ArrayList<Integer[]> result) {
   int res = 0;
   for (Integer[] ints : input) {
     if (condition(ints) {
       result.add(calculatedValue);
       res++
     }
   }
   return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, you can either

- Create a wrapper return object
- Create multiple functions

Answer (score 1):

Use an object as return value.

```
class SortedObjects { private ArrayList<Integer[]> _first; int _indexes; ...getter/setter/ctor... }

private SortedObjects sortObjects(ArrayList<Integer[]> arr) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

The simple solution is to return an array of objects.  A more robust solution is to create a class for holding the response, and use getters to get the individual values from the response object returned by your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a class which includes member variables for each piece of information you require, and return an object of that class.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use an Object which wraps the collection.

```
class SortableCollection {
    final List<Integer[]> tables = ...
    int indexes = -1;

    public void sortObjects() {
        // perform sort on tables.
        indexes = ...
    }
}
```

As it operates on a mutable object, there is no arguments or return values.