# java : return multiple values from a method

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to return multiple objects from a Java method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457629/how-to-return-multiple-objects-from-a-java-method)

lets say N= a+b;
for a number N i want to generate the all possible values a and b. like 
if N =7 a and b are (1+6),(2+5),(3+4).

i have coded this logic in a method.

```
static void sumofNum(int N){

        for(int a=1; a<N; a++){
                //a+b=N
                int b = N-a;
                System.out.println(a+","+b);
                int next =a+1;
                if(next==b | a==b)
                    return;
        }   
    }
```

i want to return (1,6),(2,5),(3,4) from this method. next for any N there can be more (a,b) combinations to be returned from this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return them as ints, define a object that contains two ints (or abuse points as I have done below) and return a list of those objects. If you define your own object, just replace point with that.

```
static ArrayList<Point> sumofNum(int N){
    ArrayList<Point> result = new ArrayList<Point>();
    for(int a=1; a<N; a++){
            //a+b=N
            int b = N-a;
        System.out.println(a+","+b);
        int next =a+1;
        if(next==b | a==b)
           result.add(new Point(a,b));
        }   
    return result;
    }
```

You can get your results from the list with:

```
results = sumofNum(7);
int a = results.get(0).x; //a = 1
int b = results.get(0).y; //b = 6
```

Answer (score 3):

Return a `List<String>` (assuming `"(1,6)"` is to be stored as a `String`). Use one of the implementations of `List`, such as `ArrayList`, to construct the list:

```
static List<String> sumofNum(int N)
{
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int a=1; a<N; a++)
    {
        int b = N-a;
        result.add("(" + a + "," + b + ")");
        int next =a+1;
        if(next==b || a==b)
            return result;
    }   
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why not to create a new type instead of using **String**?

Comment: @RoyLing, why do you need to?

Comment: It's easy to read the code and it doesn't need additionally to _split/parse_ the string in the case if you want to get the 2 int results.

Comment: @RoyLing, where does it state the two `int` results are required? If they are , then introducing a `class` containing two `int`s is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

In an object oriented (and also functional) style of programming you can pass the result to a consumer an avoid the overhead of storing results in collections or lists.

Example:

```
static void sumofNum(int N){
  for (int a=1; a<N; a++){
    //a+b=N
    int b = N-a;
    consumer.consume(a,b);
    int next =a+1;
    if (next==b || a==b)
      return;
    }   
}
```

[ Further improvements of the code are possible  (e.g. avoid the inner if and return), ... ]

Answer (score 0):

```
Consider the nos as (1,6),(2,5),(3,4)
```

**-** Now return an `ArrayList<String>` which contains each value in `String` form as "1,6" , "2,5", "3,4".

**-** When you receive the returned `ArrayList`, then use `split()` method `","` as delimiter to get the 1 and 6 out of "1,6" and so on....