# Android Project: Returning Multiple List Objects form a method

Tags: android, arraylist

I am developing an Android project in which I need to return multiple `List` objects from a method. Is this possible?

For example, I have created two different `List` objects ....

```
List<String> tid_list=new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> tno_list=new ArrayList<String>();
```

and I want to return them from a method. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457629/how-to-return-multiple-objects-from-a-java-method
It will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function can, by definition, only return one value, so you're left with a couple of options.

- You can make a new class that has `tid_list` and `tno_list` as properties of it
- You can make your method return an `ArrayList` that contains the two `ArrayList`s
- If `tno_list` and `tid_list` are properties of the class and the function is a method of the same class, you can edit them inside the method and completely skip the parameters/return value route.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1.Since lists are references, you can pass them trough argument list of the method.

2.Or you can make a class that has references to as many lists as you want.

3.You can return ArrayList of ArrayLists.