# Can I return two array types at the same time in a single method (LDL^T Factroization) in Java

Tags: java, arrays, return, matrix-decomposition

I wrote this method for LDL^T decomposition in java (It factorizes a square symmetric matrix "A" into 3 matrices where "L" is a lower triangular matrix with 1s in the diagonal and "D" is a diagonal matrix with positive entries and "L^T" is the transposed matrix of L). Was wondering if it´s possible to return the L and D matrix in the same method, if not how do I go about splitting this method. Followed the algorithm in my textbook (numerical analysis from Faires and Douglas 9th edition page 417) , my code still has some logical flaws which I have to figure out. So my question(s) is/are can I return two different types of arrays in the same method( L[][] and D[] at the same time so D only returns the diagonal elements as an array and L returns the whole matrix ) and/or how do I split this method.

```
public static double[][] Lfactor(double[][] A) {
    if (!isSquare(A)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Matrix is not square");
    }
    if (!isSymmetric(A)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Matrix is not symmetric");
    }
    int N = A.length;
    double[][] L = new double[N][N];
    double[] V = new double[N];
    double[] D = new double[N];
    for(int i=1; i <= N; i++ ){
        for(int j=1; j<=i-1;j++){
            V[j]= L[i][j]*D[j];
            double Sum1 = 0.0;
             Sum1+= L[i][j] * V[j];
             D[i] = A[i][i] - Sum1;
        for( j=i+1; j<=N;j++){
            for(int k = 1; k<=i-1; k++){
            double Sum2 = 0.0;
            Sum2 += L[j][k]*V[k];
            L[j][i]= (A[j][i] - Sum2)/D[i];
                    }
        }
    }
}
    return L;}
```

Comment: if `D[]` is a part of `L[][]` then you can just return `L[][]` and then extract `D[]` afterwards, but yea... Class container would do it, like others have suggested

Comment: This is a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457629/how-to-return-multiple-objects-from-a-java-method There's some good answers there.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers. All were helpful but had to choose one as the best answer for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a class that contains both the L and D matrices as class members, and then return an instance of this class.

Using this approach, you could then incorporate this algorithm into the class as a method, and also provide individual methods to retrieve L, D and the transposed L matrix.

For example, a class along the following lines:

```
public class LDLT
{
    private double[][] l;
    private double[][] d;

    public void calculate(double[][] a)
    {
        // calculate, and store in l and d...
    }

    public double[][] getL()
    {
        return l;
    }

    public double[][] getD()
    {
        return d;
    }

    public double[][] getTransposedL()
    {
        // calculate and transpose the l matrix...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this idea. Your answer was the most detailed and clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can only ever return one variable in a method. There are several ways to go about getting both values, but the way I would do it is to create a new class named something like LDArray, and all that class would contain would be two arrays, L and D, and getters/setters for both arrays. That way you can simply change your method to return LDArray and post both arrays in one object.

Answer (score 0):

You could return an array of `Object`s, which would contain `L` and `D`, although @Alan's suggestion is more type-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Without thinking to much, just create a class (possibly inner), call it DecompositionResults, and give it two public members: D and L. Then just assign the computed matrices to a new object of that class and return that.

Alternatively, since L is conceptually two dimensional and D is one dimensional, just return a 2D array of size N+1 x N where the last/first row is D.

Answer (score 0):

Proper programming languages have the Tuple type, which is perfectly fit for this kind of use. But Java doesn't. So you could emulate your own Pair (as a tuple of two is usually called) like this:

```
public static class Tuple<T, U> {
  public final T _1;
  public final U _2;
  public Tuple(T arg1, U arg2) {
    super();
    this._1 = arg1;
    this._2 = arg2;
  }
}
```

And use this as a return value.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the code in a Result class.

```
class LFactor {
    public final double[] L[], V, D;

    public LFactor(double[][] A) {
        if (!isSquare(A)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Matrix is not square");
        }
        if (!isSymmetric(A)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Matrix is not symmetric");
        }
        int N = A.length;
        L = new double[N][N];
        V = new double[N];
        D = new double[N];
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i - 1; j++) {
                V[j] = L[i][j] * D[j];
                double Sum1 = 0.0;
                Sum1 += L[i][j] * V[j];
                D[i] = A[i][i] - Sum1;
                for (j = i + 1; j <= N; j++) {
                    for (int k = 1; k <= i - 1; k++) {
                        double Sum2 = 0.0;
                        Sum2 += L[j][k] * V[k];
                        L[j][i] = (A[j][i] - Sum2) / D[i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BTW

```
double Sum1 = 0.0;
Sum1 += L[i][j] * V[j];
D[i] = A[i][i] - Sum1;
```

is the same as

```
D[i] = A[i][i] - L[i][j] * V[j];
```

is this what you intended?

Also your loops are likely to be simpler if you use

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
```

as this is the range of the indexes.