# I want my method to return more than one character

Tags: java

The aim of my method is to do many things at once.
Here is my code so far:

```
public static String isCode(String code) {
    code= "GUG";

    if (otherMethod(code.charAt(0)) && otherMethod(code.charAt(1))  && otherMethod(code.charAt(2)))
```

return ;

```
}
}
```

how do I then make my `isCode` method return my characters as something else through another previously made method. For example if I had a method converting one character to another,  how do I write a code that will make this happen. I tried writing `myOtherMethod(code.charAt(0)`, but how do I do this more than once to return all three values I'm looking for?

Comment: *"The aim of my method is to do many things at once."* Then this code has a problem. A method should only do _one_ thing, nothing more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return multiple objects from a Java method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457629/how-to-return-multiple-objects-from-a-java-method)

Comment: Your question is unclear. Define "return more than one value". Also update your example since "For example if I had a method converting one character to another" is very broad.

Comment: Since you're taking these characters from a String, just create a new String from the new characters.

Comment: @Pshemo by more than one value I mean at least three different characters. myOtherMethod converts one character to another, for example A becomes T and vice versa. Also after I have converted my characters in this method, I intend to take the conversion and transfer them to string.

Comment: Can't you process your input like a stream (i.e. use something like FilterReader to make your transformation)? Such filters are not that difficult to write and can be easily combined (i.e you can apply one after another at will). Not speaking about performance...Just an idea...Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Tom, if you have your method do too much stuff, you should rethink your code. But, if I'm reading your explanation correctly, I think you might have worded the question poorly. It seems like you don't want to do multiple things - you want to do one thing multiple times. It seems like the easiest way to do this would be to do something like this:

```
... else {
    char[] bases = dna.toCharArray();
    char[] newBases = new char[bases.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < bases.length; i++) {
        newBases[i] = myOtherMethod(bases[i]);
    }
    return new String(newBases);
}
```

This will use myOtherMethod on every char in dna, place them into their respective places in the new array, and then create a string out of the array to return.

The more specific way to do this is this:

```
... else {
    return new String(new char[]{myOtherMethod(firstcharacter),
        myOtherMethod(secondCharacter), myOtherMethod(thirdCharacter)});
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using a loop? Say if I wanted to write my return as (myOtherMethod(dna.charAt(0)) how do i convert that to a String?

Comment: That would just be `return new String(new char[] newBases = { myOtherMethod(firstCharacter), myOtherMethod(secondCharacter), myOtherMethod(thirdCharacter) });` On that note, why do you keep using `dna.charAt(#)`? You already assigned those characters to the first/second/thirdCharacter variables.

Comment: I did what you suggested and put 3 in the new char [] but it gave me 8 errors:
Error: ')' expected
Error: illegal start of expression
Error: ';' expected x 4
Error: illegal start of type
Error: class, interface, or enum expected

Comment: Wow. What a string of errors... Uh. Huh. Oh, right, it's because you don't want the = there. `return new String(new char[]{myOtherMethod(firstCharacter), myOtherMethod(secondCharacter), myOtherMethod(thirdCharacter)});` That should be exactly what you need.

Comment: ... Huh. Well, now, that one's a weird one. You put your return right after the else, before the closing brace, right? And your method is still signed `public static String watsonCrick`, right?

Comment: No problem, man. I just tested it myself, and it works fine. Keep it happening. :)

Comment: Doesn't limit it? What do you mean? If you want to have a variable amount of characters, you're going to need to use an array and a loop, absolutely.

Comment: Oh. Then just add another statement in your if: `|| code.length > 3`, just put that on the end of the current three checks.

Answer (score 0):

That's really up to you.

One way would be returning a `String`, since it is pretty much a collection of characters. If you have a `String` object you can just concatenate a character like

```
String result = "";
if (isValidBase(dna.charAt(0)) {
    result += dna.charAt(0);
}else{
    return "";
}
if (isValidBase(dna.charAt(1)) {
    result += dna.charAt(1);
}else{
    return "";
}
// etc
return result;
```

You could also just return a `char[]`, which is an array of `char`. If you know the size (3), then you make it like

```
char[] result = new char[3];
```

And then fill in the values and finally

```
return result;
```

You could use an `ArrayList<char>` too, but that's probably going to be a bit overkill for your purposes.

There are many ways to return multiple values. You need to be more specific on your needs.