# Return an ArrayList and int value from a single method. Is it Possible?

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, return

I'm working on my coursework and came up with this situation. Here's my code.

```
public static ArrayList<Student> checkPresent(String unitID, String week){
    int present = 0;
    ArrayList<Student> studentDetails = Student.getStudentDetails();

    ArrayList<AttendanceLog> pickedList = AttendanceLog.pickFromAttendanceLog(unitID, week);

    for(Student student : studentDetails){
        student.setPresent("N");
        for(AttendanceLog attendance : pickedList){
            if(student.getStudentNo().equals(attendance.getStudentID())){
                student.setPresent("Y");
                present++;
            }

        }
    }

    return studentDetails;

}
```

I have only returned the `ArrayList` but I also want to get the integer value `present`. Is it possible? Or how can I take the int value ?

Comment: you can encapsulate the arraylist and integer in a class and return its object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return multiple objects from a Java method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457629/how-to-return-multiple-objects-from-a-java-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create class holing the arraylist and the integer.
`classname name = new classname();
name.integerValue= integerValue;
name.arraylist= arraylist;
return arraylist;`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can create a class which holds both an ArrayList as well as an integer

```
class SomeClass{
ArrayList<Student> aList;
int present;
}
```

and have your method return an instance of this class

UPDATE:

```
public static SomeClass checkPresent(String unitID, String week){

int present = 0;
ArrayList<Student> studentDetails = Student.getStudentDetails();

ArrayList<AttendanceLog> pickedList = AttendanceLog.pickFromAttendanceLog(unitID, week);

for(Student student : studentDetails){
    student.setPresent("N");
    for(AttendanceLog attendance : pickedList){
        if(student.getStudentNo().equals(attendance.getStudentID())){
            student.setPresent("Y");
            present++;
        }

    }
}
SomeClass someCls = new SomeClass();
someCls.present = present;
someCls.aList = studentDetails;
return someCls;

}
```

Note that in your example you're obtaining studentDetails statically, so it wouldn't make much sense to code it this way because you can always get the students list by calling Student.getStudentDetails().

Comment: Can you please explain it further more with a sample code ?

Comment: Thank you! It was really usefull

Answer (score 3):

You can only return one thing from a method.

You have to options :

1. pass the ArrayList as an argument to the method. The caller would instantiate the ArrayList and the method would populate it. Then your method can return the `int` you wish to return in addition to the `ArrayList`.
2. Wrap the `ArrayList` and `int` in some custom class and change your method to return an instance of that class (you can also do that with an `Object[]`, but that would be ugly).

Answer (score 0):

I like to create a new type that has the  ArrayList and int as members.

```
class Result {
    public final int value;
    public final List<> list;

    public Result(int val, List<> list) {
        this.value = val;
        this.list = list;
}
```