# Returning multplie values of the same type in Java

Tags: java, return-value, return-type

I need to return 3 values of an object I created in a method I created. I can put this code in my while loop and it executes how I want it to execute. But I want to keep it in a method just to modularize my program and keep the code organized. Im using the ACM library which is for academia purposes.

```
        public GObject asteroidLocation(){

               if(asteroid1.getX() >= AW)
               {
                    asteroid1.setLocation(0,150);
               }
               else if(asteroid2.getX() >= AW)
               {
                    asteroid2.setLocation(0,80);
               }

               else if(asteroid3.getX() >= AW)
               {
                   asteroid3.setLocation(0,20);
               }
                   return asteroid1, asteroid2, asteroid3;
         }
```

Comment: Aaaand, what is the question?

Comment: Ah, I see, let me answer that quick ;)

Comment: You need to put your objects into a Collection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return multiple objects from a Java method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457629/how-to-return-multiple-objects-from-a-java-method)

Comment: Not complete overlap between the questions, since that is about encapsulation, and this might be about collections, that is a more specific form of that.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a `java.util.List`

For your use-case you could just do this:

```
return Arrays.asList(asteroid1, asteroid2, asteroid3);
```

Your return type then would be `List<GObject>`

Comment: Thank you sir. Using the acm library is kind of confusing when you implement standard Java with it. But I have to start somewhere. Cant start at the top.

Answer (score 0):

So return a `List<Asteroid>` or whatever type asteroid is. Even better is have an object you create that has a `List<Asteroid>`, has a `getAsteroids()` method and return that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Tuples (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) and Triples?
Java don't provide any but it's pretty straightforward to implement. I can give you an example if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the value outside the if condition return it from within. For example,

```
    if(asteroid1.getX >= AW)
    {
       asteroid1.setLocation(0,150);
       return asteroid1;
    }
```

This way you could simplify the code and pass only one return value to the class

Answer (score 0):

A direct answer to you question "*multplie values of the same type in Java*" would be:

- An array: `GObject[]`
- Any generic collection, e.g. `List<GObject>`