# How to return multiple objects from one Java method?

Tags: java, methods, return

In here I'm trying to return two results as one response and not sure what option may good with it.
In here it return as a list,

```
List<FixedDeposit> fdList = em.createQuery(sb.toString())
            .setParameter("start", dateFrom)
            .setParameter("end", dateTo)
            .setFirstResult(start).setMaxResults(limit)
            .getResultList();
```

so I have got it as

```
List<FDSearchResult> searchList = getSearchResult(fdList); 
response.setData(searchList);
return response;
```

And now again I want to return another response. And this is the calculation,

```
Double sum = 0.0;
sum = (Double) em.createQuery("SELECT SUM(deposit_amount)FROM fd_fixed_deposit where fd.status in ('ACT','REN','WDR') and fd.maturityDate between :start and :end ")
                .setParameter("start", dateFrom)
                .setParameter("end", dateTo).getSingleResult();
```

So how can I return the result through response for the sum? Please Help

I will post the full method,

```
public Response<List<FDSearchResult>> loadMaturedFDByRange(String fromDate, String toDate, final Integer start,
        final Integer limit) {
    final Response<List<FDSearchResult>> response = new Response<List<FDSearchResult>>();
    Date dateFrom = DateUtils.parseDate("dd/MM/yyyy", fromDate, null);
    Date dateTo = DateUtils.parseDate("dd/MM/yyyy", toDate, null);
    Long count = 0L;
    Double sum = 0.0;
    try {
        count = (Long) em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(fd) FROM FixedDeposit fd where fd.status in ('ACT','REN','WDR') "
                + "and fd.maturityDate between :start and :end ")
                .setParameter("start", dateFrom)
                .setParameter("end", dateTo).getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException nre) {
        count = 0L;
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("SELECT fd FROM FixedDeposit fd where fd.status in ('ACT','REN','WDR') and fd.maturityDate between :start and :end ");
    List<FixedDeposit> fdList = em.createQuery(sb.toString())
            .setParameter("start", dateFrom)
            .setParameter("end", dateTo)
            .setFirstResult(start).setMaxResults(limit)
            .getResultList();

    sum = (Double) em.createQuery("SELECT SUM(deposit_amount)FROM fd_fixed_deposit where fd.status in ('ACT','REN','WDR') and fd.maturityDate between :start and :end ")
                .setParameter("start", dateFrom)
                .setParameter("end", dateTo).getSingleResult();

    List<FDSearchResult> searchList = getSearchResult(fdList);
    response.setData(searchList);
    response.setPagination(new Response().new PaginationInfo(count));
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).

Comment: Returning a map could help, so you can organize your objects in it

Comment: If it's always going to be 2 objects of that type, create another object to store them both and return that.

Comment: The types are not same, fdList - list and sum is not a list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return multiple objects from a Java method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457629/how-to-return-multiple-objects-from-a-java-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this instance, I would create an Object Container that holds these two objects and return that object instead.

```
public class MyContainer
{
   List<FixedDeposit> fdList;
   List<FDSearchResult> searchList;

   public MyContainer()
   {

   }
}
```

This is how I would approach this.

Answer (score 1):

You can return all relevant data via result objects.
Just create a new class which can obtain all your needed values.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. HashMap. Type cast Object to response and Double respectively. This is not a good practice
2. You can create a custom class which can encapsulate different object types.
   Generics is what you need here.

   ```
   public class MultiReturn<T> {
     public final String name;
     public final T object;

     public NamedObject(String name, T object) {
        this.name = name;
        this.object = object;
     }
   }
   ```