# How to assign variables from an array in one line

Tags: java, arrays, variable-assignment

Is there an elegant way to do the following: let int[] makeArray() be a method
that returns a length 2 integer array. Then

```
int[] t = makeArray(); int ta = t[0]; tb = t[1];
```

Nicer would be

```
int[] {ta,tb} = makeArray();
```

Comment: Are you trying to create an array based off of the values of `ta` and `tb` or are you trying to resolve the values in the array to `ta` and `tb`?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't unless `makeArray()` returns the same array after each call (which I'm assuming it doesn't due to its name). If this is the case, however, you could write:

```
int ta = makeArray()[0];
int tb = makeArray()[1];
```

Otherwise, the value returned from `makeArray()` would need to be cached so that it can be used to set the variables that follow it.

Answer (score -1):

What you're describing is returning multiple values, which would be nice but [isn't supported in java, you have to wrap them in an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/457629/2187042).

However depending on your use case you could refactor into something elegant using lambdas, e.g. the following where I've rearranged so the `makeArray` becomes `withDataArray` and you pass it a lambda to process the array data. You could make it have a return easily enough as well. Change `BiConsumer` to `BiFunction` and have withDataArray return the result of the `BiFunction`

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    withDataArray( (a,b) -> {
        System.out.println(a+b);
    });

}

public static void withDataArray(BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> applier){
    applier.accept(1,2);
}
```