# How to get integer and fraction portions of a BigDecimal in Java

Tags: java, integer, bigdecimal

For a [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) number such as 42.7, how can I tear this apart to get the integer part (42) and the decimal fractional part (0.7)?

I would like to retrieve both as `BigDecimal` objects. But I will take what I can get and make `BigDecimal` object from them.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
myBigDecimal
.divideAndRemainder( BigDecimal.ONE )
[ 0 ]                                    // for integer part
```

…and…

```
[ 1 ]                                    // for fraction part
```

## `BigDecimal::divideAndRemainder`

The [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class offers some methods for this.

The [`BigDecimal::divideAndRemainder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divideAndRemainder(java.math.BigDecimal)) method divides your original number by another number. The result is an array of two `BigDecimal` objects, the first being the integer portion and the second being the fraction amount.

To achieve your goal, we merely need to divide by one. The `BigDecimal` class offers a constant object for the value of one: [`BigDecimal.ONE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ONE).

```java
BigDecimal input = new BigDecimal( "42.7" ) ;
BigDecimal[] parts = input.divideAndRemainder( BigDecimal.ONE );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( Arrays.toString( parts ) );
```

> [42.0, 0.7]

Grab each piece from the array.

```java
BigDecimal input = new BigDecimal( "42.7" ) ;
BigDecimal[] parts = input.divideAndRemainder( BigDecimal.ONE );
BigDecimal integerPart = parts[ 0 ] ;
BigDecimal fractionPart = parts[ 1 ] ;
```

If you only need one part:

- `myBigDecimal.divideAndRemainder( BigDecimal.ONE )[ 0 ]` integer part
- `myBigDecimal.divideAndRemainder( BigDecimal.ONE )[ 1 ]` fraction part

[Addition](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#add(java.math.BigDecimal)) puts them [together again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humpty_Dumpty).

```
BigDecimal humptyDumpty = integerPart.add( fractionPart ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

### setScale()

I think I’d go for `setScale()`.

```
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("42.7");
    
    BigDecimal integerPart = bd.setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN);
    BigDecimal fractionalPart = bd.subtract(integerPart);
    
    System.out.println(integerPart);
    System.out.println(fractionalPart);
```

> ```
> 42
> 0.7
> ```

It seems to me to be clear to read.