# Java - return multiple return types

Tags: java, class, inheritance, return

I am currently writing a programm that reads in a CSV file and then creates objects of the type Member or Trainer, depending on the first char in each line (M/T). I want the function parseLine to return the new Object. The class trainer inherits from Member and the code "works" but the additional variables of the Trainer class get lost when returning it as a "Member". Is there any possibility to return a trainer object in that function or to call another function that helps?
Thanks.

```
 public static Member parseLine(final String line) {
    try {
        String[] lines = line.split(";");
        String[] sports = lines[2].split(",");

       Map<Sports,Level> temp = new LinkedHashMap<Sports,Level>();

       for(int count = 0; count < sports.length/2; ++count) {
           temp.put(Sports.valueOf(sports[count].toUpperCase()), Level.valueOf(sports[count+1].toUpperCase()));
           ++count;
       }

       if(lines[0]=="T")
           return new Trainer(lines[1],temp);
       else
           return new Member(lines[1],temp);
       
      } catch (Exception e) {
          System.err.println("Exception occured: " + e);
      }
      return null;
    
}
```

Comment: Disambiguate using `returnedObject instanceof Trainer`. I'd also recommend rethrowing the exception instead of returning null.

Comment: you should use downcast to type Trainer in your will invoked code.

Answer (score 1):

The additional members are not lost; you just need to know when to attempt to cast the returned `Member` to a `Trainer`.

i.e. use `instanceof` at the calling site, or cast the returned value using `(Trainer)foo`, say, and check if the resulting expression is `null` or otherwise.

That said, this is normally symptomatic of poor design, as it defeats the purpose of polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to return an object with both a Trainer and a Member, but have one of them be null.

You could return a [Pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457629/how-to-return-multiple-objects-from-a-java-method) which contains Trainer and Member but only initialize one for them to usable values. Then on the receiving end, you check if Trainer is valid, else it's a Member.

The specific code I was referencing was this response:

```
public class Pair<A,B> {
public final A a;
public final B b;

public Pair(A a, B b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
};
```

You could just adapt the types A and B to be your Trainer and Member